# Growth of analytic function at infinity, provided a bound in all but one directions.

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let's consider a function of a complex variable $f(z)$, with the following properties:

- $f(z)$ is bounded by a constant as $z \to \infty$ away from the positive real axis ($z \notin \mathbb{R}^+$)
- $f(z)$ is analytic in the interior of the domain $\mathcal{D} = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : -\epsilon<\arg z < \epsilon \} $, for some finite positive $\epsilon$.

Can one conclude that $f(z)$ is bounded by the same constant also on the positive real axis?

Arguments like the [Phragmén–Lindelöf principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phragm%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_principle) get close, but they require some bound on the positive real axis. However, here we know that the function is bounded everywhere, not just on the boundary of a sector, and the boundaries of the sector can get arbitrarily close to the positive real axis.

What I have in mind, specifically, is a function which is analytic away from the negative real axis, and for which I can prove a bound of the following type:

$$z=r e^{\mathbb{i} \theta}, \qquad \lim_{r \to \infty} \left| f(z) \right|(1-\cos\theta)^\alpha <+\infty, $$
for some finite positive $\alpha$.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Seems that this follows from the maximum modulus theorem. For fixed $R$ consider the sector of radius $R$ and opening angle $2\epsilon$. Then $f$ ist bounded in the boundary of this sector, hence on the whole sector

Comment: unless you know something more like some uniformity, the result is not true since there are entire functions that have the property that $\lim_{r \to \infty}f(re^{i\theta})=0$ for every $\theta$ (where of course the limit is highly not uniform so $f$ is actually highly unbounded overall)

Comment: Hi. Thanks @BrunoKrams! I think maximum modulus cannot be applied directly when the region is unbounded. For instance, consider the function $e^{z^{\pi/2\epsilon}}$. The Phragmen Lindelof theorem address these cases.

Comment: @Conrad, could you give an example please? What do you mean by "unbounded overall"? If the statement is valid for every $\theta$ then it does not seem to contradict the (unproven) claim. More generally, all the cases I can think of oscillate wildly so they grow also away from the positive real axis. Thanks!

Comment: it is not hard to prove that $H(z)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{tz}t^{-t}dt$ is an entire function that satisfies $|H(x+iy)| \le \frac{1}{|y|-\pi/2}$ for $|y| >\pi/2$ and every $x$ which means that $g(z)=H(z+ic)$ is bounded on any line that passes through zero as long as $c >\pi/2$  and then $f(z)=\frac{g(z)-g(0)}{z}$ obviously is entire and satisfies $f(re^{i\theta}) \to 0, r \to \infty$ for fixed $\theta$; even more one can construct with elementary integrals entire functions that go to zero at infinity on every line in the plane; see the paper of D Armitage  https://www.jstor.org/stable/27642171

Comment: I see, thanks a lot @Conrad. I think $H$ already provides a counterexample. I can  clarify maybe the first line of my question: asking for a function that is asymptotically bounded along any straight line passing by the origin, except along the positive real axis. $H$ grows fast ($e^{z/2+e^{z-1}}$) on the real axis but is bounded in all other directions eventually, because one exits the strip. Would you like to promote your comment to an answer or should I write it? I am not sure what is the etiquette.